# Post request Amazon S3 with AFNetworking

Tags: objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, afnetworking-2

I'm posting an image to Amazon S3 via AFNetworking, and getting a strange error. The file is uploading, but once it hits 100% it returns an error:

```
Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: method not allowed (405)"



AFAmazonS3Manager *s3manager = [[AFAmazonS3Manager alloc] initWithAccessKeyID:AWS_Access_Key secret:AWS_Secret_Key];
s3manager.requestSerializer.region = AFAmazonS3USWest1Region;
s3manager.requestSerializer.bucket = AWS_Bucket_Name;


//setting for image url name
NSString* destionationPathForS3 = @"1234567";

[s3manager postObjectWithFile:self.filePath
              destinationPath:destionationPathForS3
                   parameters:nil
                     progress:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
                         NSLog(@"%f%% Uploaded", (totalBytesWritten / (totalBytesExpectedToWrite * 1.0f) * 100));
                     }
                      success:^(id responseObject) {
                          NSURL *resultURL = [s3manager.requestSerializer.endpointURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:destionationPathForS3];
                          NSLog(@"Upload Complete: %@", resultURL);
                      }
                      failure:^(NSError *error) {
                          NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                      }];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not really sure why, but changing the below worked for me:

```
postObjectWithFile:
```

to

```
putObjectWithFile:
```

Comment: Bucket public "WRITE" access: This is sometimes referred to as "put" or "upload" access. It allows anyone to add/delete/replace objects in your Amazon S3 bucket.
For detail - https://aws.amazon.com/articles/Amazon-S3/5050